# Installing openvpn problem on ubuntu

Tags: openvpn, downloads

I executed:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

But I cannot find the installation config file in `Downloads`.
I need to find it.

How can I do it?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using the desktop or the server? Do you want to install the client or the server for openvpn? [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1322792/edit) and add all these information.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO: Its easier if you use the openvpn-install script for the server side.

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angristan/openvpn-install/master/openvpn-install.sh
chmod +x openvpn-install.sh
sudo bash openvpn-install.sh
```

This will prompt you for setup options just take its suggestion and its done in minutes.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-openvpn-in-ubuntu/

For the client.. Using the client config file build above.

```
sudo apt install openvpn
openvpn --config /path/to/configuration.ovpn
```

https://serverspace.io/support/help/install-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: Thank you, but in 11th sentence, I can not write scp command's features